# What is the Dollar sign ("$") at the end of every line in Vim

Tags: vim

I am relatively new to Vim. Whenever I start Vim using `vim LearnRuby.rb`, a dollar sign appears at every line.

Why?

Comment: @cppcoder  Probably the first, as that is the dollarsign ;)

Comment: @LivingThing `$` is marking the end of the line, but by default it is not printed, should be some setting.

Comment: @Bernhard : Any idea how to make it invisible ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [$ sign at end of each line in vim, however, it doesn't appear in other computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350958/sign-at-end-of-each-line-in-vim-however-it-doesnt-appear-in-other-computer)

Comment: I originally marked the newer question as a duplicate of this one, but the answers here are actually not as good as those, so I have reverted the nomination and am instead nominating this one for closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
:set nolist
```

will turn off special characters for the current buffer, such as tabs being presented as `^I` and end of line characters showing up as `$`.

However, if it's doing that consistently when you run `vim`, you need to look into your `.vimrc` (or other startup file where applicable) and find out what's doing the `set list` that causes it.

Answer (score 2):

Open `~/.vimrc` and check its contents
If you see a line like this:

```
set list
```

It means, it will display `$` in every line to mark the end of line.
Either remove it or use `:set nolist` command in the vi editor.

Comment: It can also be in the system vimrc done by a weird administrator.

Comment: I think you'll find that "weird administrator" is a bit redundant :-)

Comment: Two answers and both suggesting turning list off instead of tweaking listchars. It is really useful option for showing tabs and trailing spaces.

Comment: I also found that editing listchars is probably a better way.

Comment: @ZyX So why not add that as a separate answer?

Comment: See now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350958/sign-at-end-of-each-line-in-vim-however-it-doesnt-appear-in-other-computer which has several good answers to address that.

Comment: I added it as an answer since it's mental that it isn't here just because it is on a different question. Very old question but it has been "active" relatively recently and, well, I found it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the solution is not to `:set nolist`, as that also disables other characters like tabs and trailing spaces, which can be very useful. :set nolist would be the correct answer if you wanted all of the special characters gone.

If you just want a quick fix, you could add this to your vimrc instead:

`set listchars+=eol:\` .

That is a backslash followed by a whitespace.

Alternatively you can set all the arguments of listchars, for example`set listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:.` and not include the eol argument, which determines the character used for end of line.

Refer to `:h listhcars` and `:h list`

Answer (score 0):

edit -[ /home/$USER/.config/nvim/init.vim ]->
by commenting (adding a " just before eol) - the line -[ set listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:+,eol:$ ]->
so it looks like this -[ set listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:+,"eol:$ ]-

Answer (score -1):

In order to remove the symbols inside the code editor you must go to the folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT0Xj.png)

Add in any part of the opt, the following line of code: opt.list = false, save and you won't have that problem anymore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdRI7.png)

Comment: This is a solution for NeoVim but the OP asked about Vim. Also please make sure to NOT use screenshots where text would suffice