# $ sign at end of each line in vim, however, it doesn't appear in other computer

Tags: linux, vim

I have two computers installed Debian. I first configured vim in computer A, and everything is fine. After I copied the `.vimrc` file to computer B, however, there are always `$` at each line's end.

After some googles, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735560/dollar-sign-at-the-end-of-every-line). I followed it, and `$` sign disappeared. But, I am used to `set list` to keep codes indent neatly. Where did I get wrong? How to fix this hard problem?

---

**Update:**

I have checked my `.vimrc` file, and found `set listchars=tab:›\ ,trail:•,extends:#,nbsp:.`. But when I open vim each time an error -- `E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:�~@�\ ,trail:�~@�,extends:#,nbsp:.` -- is reported. Is there any encoding problem in my computer?

---

**Update:**

Finally, this problem is resolved by add `set encoding=utf-8` to `.vimrc`. Thanks to all the kindness guys.

Comment: Actually, I think my problem is different from that. From [Dollar sign at the end of every line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735560/dollar-sign-at-the-end-of-every-line), I know `set nolist` will turn `$` sign off. In my problem, however, I not only want to set `set list` on but also to turn `$` sign off.

Comment: I agree, and have redacted my close vote. The answers here are already more useful than the old answers, so I'm actually now voting to close the old question as a duplicate of this one instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h 'listchars'`

```
'listchars' 'lcs'   string  (default "eol:$")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Strings to use in 'list' mode and for the |:list| command.  It is a
    comma separated list of string settings.
```

Try executing `:set listchars?` in vim in your computer A to know what option is being used, then write it in your `.vimrc`. E.g.

```
set listchars=tab:>-
```

It's probably better to try with `:verbose set listchars?` which tells us where the option is last set. This might help find what is the actual cause of the different behaviours in your computer A and B.

Comment: Yeah, there is a `listchars` option set in `.vimrc`. But, I also get `E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:�~@�\ ,trail:�~@�,extends:#,nbsp:.` error...

Comment: You probably need `scriptencoding utf-8` (or whatever encoding you're using) in the `.vimrc`.

Comment: It is actually caused by wrong encoding. After added `set encoding=utf-8` to `.vimrc` file and reopened vim, troubles gone. ^-^

Answer (score 2):

You can keep `list` enabled but disable the `$` sign at the end of every line.

Check the output of `:set listchars`, and update it with the `eol:$` part removed.

For example (I assume you use `list` for marking tab indentation):

```
:set listchars=tab:>-
```

Comment: When I open vim, `E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:�~@�\ ,trail:�~@�,extends:#,nbsp:.` is poped up. I think some encoding errors exist.